# How to prevent loading all fragments data at once using TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, dynamic-list

I've implemented **android.support.design.widget.TabLayout** in my application. The tab contains dynamic data that comes from the API and also the dynamic content in a fragment. 
I'm calling the Tab wise APIs. But in my fragment all APIs calling the first fragment. So, it takes too much load to show the data. 
I want to call API particular tab wise. When the user will click to tab then API should be called.

I've set ArrayList size to `offscreenPageLimit` like below

```
viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = mTaskStatusListResult.size
```

After researched I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455160/9635628
and set `viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 1`
But still, the second tab's data are loading. i.e When a user enters the screen it loads first & second data when clicking the second tab the loads' third data.
I want to prevent that. Can you pls help. It'll be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem time ago and I couldn't find a way, the way to only load the current fragment should be `offscreenPageLimit = 0` but when I tested it I found out that offscreenPageLimit internally behaves as it was 1 even if you set it to 0.

Comment: I think you should set `offscreenPageLimit` to zero, but you'll also get the same effect. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is inside `Fragment's` `setUserVisibleHint` overriden method

```
private boolean isViewShown = false;

    @Override 
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { 
         super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);      
    if (getView() != null && isVisibleToUser) { 
         isViewShown = true; 
         callAPI(); 
    } else { 
         isViewShown = false; 
    } 
}
```

This method is called when that fragment is visible only and here you can call the required API to load data.

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated

Comment: ``setUserVisibleHint`` is deprecated I used the override function ``setMenuVisibility `` and it worked .

Answer (score 1):

Viewpager has default property to initialize two page at same time so you can not change that but you can setOffscreenPageLimit as par your need

ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)

if it not working you can try another way Call API in Fragment visible method

public class MyFragment extends Fragment

{

@Override

public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible)

{

super.setMenuVisibility(visible);

```
    if (visible) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

// ...
}

Comment: you can try with  fragment visible method